# Dynamically creating pods with kubernetes by a queue

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I have a service and it can process only one request at a time. I deployed service with kubernetes.

I want this: Every request will be put in a RabbitMQ queue. When the top request in the queue is sent, a new pod will create. The pod will be destroyed after the service at docker container ends. A new pod will open for the new request. Also, there will be a limit for pod count. New request in queue will be held when the limit is reached.

Can you guide me for this use case???

Answer (score 2):

You can use [knative](https://knative.dev). Knative is a Serverless framework which automatically  create pod when there is an [event](https://github.com/cloudevents/spec). [Rabbitmq](https://github.com/Justin2997/knative-rabbitmq-to-lambda-source) as an event source is in progress.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do knative eventing exactly creates new pod each time event comes in? Where to find documentation reference about it? (I couldn't find) I want to ensure that it is, cause my case require spawning each pod for each event, process it and then exit. Does knative eventing allow that?